# Problem with reading data from ELM327

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, c++, c, hc-05

The idea was to create a bluetooth device on the arduino to read data from the machine (ELM327 v2.1) using the HC-05 bluetooth module.

In this code the bluetooth module is switched to MASTER mode and connected to ELM327 using its MAC address. The responses of the module in the code are in the comments.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial bluetoothSerial(4, 5);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("READY");
  bluetoothSerial.begin(38400);
  delay(1000);
  getSetAtCommand("AT");                         //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+CMODE=0");                 //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+PSWD=1234");               //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+ROLE=1");                  //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+BIND=0010,CC,4F3603");     //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+LINK=0010,CC,4F3603");     //OK
  delay(1000);
  getSetAtCommand("AT+STATE?");  // OK: CONNECTED
  delay(1000);
  getSetAtCommand("ATZ");      //no answer, the buffer is empty                
  getSetAtCommand("AT015B");//no answer, the buffer is empty
  getSetAtCommand("015B");      //no answer, the buffer is empty          
  getSetAtCommand("ATRV");   //no answer, the buffer is empty
  getSetAtCommand("0105");    //no answer, the buffer is empty                  
  getSetAtCommand("at i");   //no answer, the buffer is empty
  getSetAtCommand("at rv");   //no answer, the buffer is empty                   
  getSetAtCommand("ati");    //no answer, the buffer is empty  
  getSetAtCommand("atrv");   //no answer, the buffer is empty
}

void loop() {
}

void getSetAtCommand(String command) {
  Serial.println(command);
  String added_command = command + "\r\n";
  bluetoothSerial.print(added_command);
  delay(500);
  while (bluetoothSerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(bluetoothSerial.read());
  }
}
```

Since the State returns CONNECTED, I assume that it is connected to the ELM.

To the command `AT+PAIR=0010,CC,4F3603,20\r\n` the module does not respond. The module also does not respond to commands such as `ATZ\r\n, AT015B\r\n, 015B\r\n, ATRV\r\n, 0105\r\n, at i\r\n, at rv\r\n, ati\r\n, atrv\r\n`. Sometimes the answer is `ERROR[0]`, as I understand it means that there is no such command.

It seems to me that these commands don't reach the ELM at all. What can be the problem?

The ELM327 itself works, connects to the phone without any problems and shows the data.

Tried through the simulator on a laptop, the connected bluetooth model is displayed in the bluetooth devices on the laptop and also does not work as with the ELM.

Comment: Do you have a manual or doc for ELM327 v2.1 that you can share?

Comment: @Fahad unfortunately not if you find on the Internet

Comment: I can't seem to find it. How do you know of the AT commands? Is there an instruction somewhere?

Comment: try `AT$` ... it worked on old modems to display the available command set ... maybe the command is also implemented in your device